# Open CV - Transform MatOfPoint3f using Rotation Matrix?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, opencv, mediapipe, pose-estimation

OpenCV : [OpenCVForUnity](https://enoxsoftware.github.io/OpenCVForUnity/3.0.0/doc/html/index.html)
MediaPipe: [MediaPipeUnityPlugin](https://github.com/homuler/MediaPipeUnityPlugin)

I have a rotation matrix from face landmarks (generated by MediaPipe) using solvePnP called rvec (below). I have tested that the resultant rotation is accurate in estimating head pose. However, I want to use this matrix to rotate the MatOfPoint3f object containing the face landmarks back to a "forward facing" direction. I have tried using `OpenCVForUnity.CoreModule.Core.transform(MatLandmarks, MatLandmarks, rmat.inv())` but the transformed values still are affected by the movement of the head. Any ideas?

```
Calib3d.solvePnP(object_points, image_points, camMatrix, distCoeffs, rvec, tvec);
Calib3d.Rodrigues(rvec, rmat);
```